# bind custom properties to android internal view

Tags: android

I have more than 20+ `TextView` and `ImageView` in my activity like this:

```
<GridLayout id="layout">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/t1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" .../>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/t2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" .../>
    ......
</GridLayout>
```

Each `TextView` or `ImageView` have a related code.

Now I tried to handle the click event for the child Views, the logic is rather simple, fetch data from server by different code.

I know the general method maybe this:

```
findViewById("layout").setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void click(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.t1 :
            doSearch(1);
        break;
        case R.id.t2 :
            doSearch(2);
        break;
        .....
    }
}
```

Then I have to too many `case`s .

Then I wonder if I can bind the code to the `View` directly, perhaps like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/t1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" xx:code="1" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/t2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" xx:code="2" .../>
```

Then I can handle the event in this way:

```
@Override
public void click(View v){
    doSearch(v.getCode());
}
```

Is this possible or any other alternatives?

Comment: what is the need for creating the view seperatwly why cant you try us some type listviews or gridviews baby

Comment: Since some grid will cover over multiple columns or rows, so I have to add these view manually.

Comment: can you put a pain draw how your app should be ... I will give you the best idea

Comment: Ok. Two or three minutes.

Comment: take up your own time baby

Comment: @TonyStark: Check this. http://imgbin.org/images/15571.png  Thanks.

Comment: http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=15572 see this link if you implemented in that way  your code will be less and efficent

Comment: Ok, I will have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `tag`. In your xml:

```
<GridLayout id="layout">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/t1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:tag="1" .../>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/t2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:tag="2" .../>
    ......
</GridLayout>
```

and in your activity:

```
@Override
public void click(View v){
    doSearch((String)v.getTag());
}
```